# How to store data in Cient side in blackberry device

Tags: javascript, blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

Hi I am developing app using IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio7.0.0.00.

I heared that Blackberry does not support JSONStore.What are the options to store data in Blackberry device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### I think the best for this issues is localForage.js

See the [reference](https://mozilla.github.io/localForage/#localforage) and the [GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) page for more info.

LocalForage stores data in IndexedDB, WebSQL or LocalStorage in a fallBack style.
I like this lib because in mobile devices, you can define custom drivers and link the getters and setters to a custom SQLite database, with Cordova/Phonegap or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 LocalStorage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

For example:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```